# Cann't install Ubuntu Desktop in Vmware,but winxp normal

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, desktop

vmware version = 14.1.2
host os = Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit , Service Pack 1.
8 GB RAM.
When i install ubuntu desktop 16 and  18 in vmware as guest os,vmware-vmx.exe lose response and vmware stop in install welcome screen .But install ubuntu server and  winxp is normal .

What is the problem,and how to fix it?
[install ubuntu desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac7RN.png)

Comment: Have you verified your configuration and installation process against blogs like the following? https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-on-vmware-workstation-guest-machines/

Comment: Thank u for you tip.I find the cause which is compatible problem,when i set vmware-vmx.exe only use integrated graphics but not use nvidia  gtx960m diver ,the desktop ubuntu run normal.